# Scrapy search form follows an inexistent page

Tags: python, forms, request, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the results from certain  keywords using the advanced search form of The Guardian.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class IndependentSpider(Spider):
    name = "IndependentSpider"
    start_urls= ["http://www.independent.co.uk/advancedsearch"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield [FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={"all": "Science"}, callback=self.parse_results)]

    def parse_results(self):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        print hxs.select('//h3').extract()
```

The form redirects me to

```
DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.independent.co.uk/ind/advancedsearch/> from <GET http://www.independent.co.uk/advancedsearch>
```

which is a page that doesn't seem to exist.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need a trailing `/`.

Try `start_urls= ["http://www.independent.co.uk/advancedsearch/"]`